# How can i restore auto - replace values in Toad for Oracle

Tags: oracle, autocomplete, settings, restore, toad

I am using Toad for Oracle 11.
I had some auto - replace values apart from the defaults (to do this go to View - Toad Options - Auto - replace button and from there is kind of straightforward).

I was trying to add an auto - replace value of more than one SQL, so i thought it was good to save the SQL s in a query and choose the import option. After doing this, i lost all my previously defined values, even the defaults.

In order to restore the default values, there is a Restore Defaults button.

**Can i restore all the values i explicitly defined (not sure if there is a way to restore older settings of Toad)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot recover your previous Auto Replace. If you Restore Defaults and click Cancel on the options dialog you should get your previous setup. If you've clicked Restore Defaults and then exited the Options dialog with OK or have clicked Apply then you're finished. The Import feature imports from an Auto Replace datafile which is not the same as a file you create containing SQL.

Auto Replace is best suited for single words, common misspellings, etc. If you want to have a quick way to insert commonly used SQL then you should look at Code Templates.